# What kind of a GoPro/tripod mount can attach the camera to a helmet with screws?

Tags: helmets, cameras

I'm looking to install a GoPro camera on my helmet, but I would like to screw in the mount rather than using adhesives as I don't trust them to be reliable enough. But when I search for helmet mounts on Amazon, they all seemingly use adhesives rather than being designed for screws.

How can I find the mount that I'm looking for? Presumably there's a keyword that I'm missing or I should be searching for something other than "helmet mount"?

Comment: I wouldn't advise screwing into a helmet, especially if your helmet is of the sacrificial type (cycle/motorcycle for example). If you don't trust the adhesive use an elastic strap mount and make sure you have a tether.

Comment: All helmets I own explicitly warn against this sort of thing - if you drill into a helmet you remove its strength. It will not protect you. Use adhesive mounts - they are reliable enough to stay on unless you have a bad impact. And in those cases you definitely want the camera to break away and not force the helmet to break.

Comment: This page [12 Best GoPro Helmet Mounts](https://clicklikethis.com/gopro-helmet-mounts/) has some fixed by adhesive, some by screws, and some by **straps**.

Comment: @WeatherVane the article is a bit misleading - none appear to be designed to screw directly to the helmet, when you go to the actual product descrptions.  The ones that use (clamp) screws are interfaces that join to an adhesive or strap helmet mount, or another mount

Comment: I have to say, while I think the idea is bad, the question is a good one - though I'm about to edit the title to include the word "helmet" as there are myriad screw-mounts for other places

Comment: BTW the tripod screw fitting (I assume GoPros have them, I only have cheap cameras) is fairly likely to come undone under vibration. A single-screw mount has to be designed to resist rotary forces, or to have a lock, or be capable of being done up hard, and those don't reliably apply to action use

Comment: sound like a good way to get really hurt.

Comment: The adhesive mounts are surprisingly strong. They are not easy to get off at all. They have survived the wind at over 100mph for me so I doubt much will pull them off unless deliberate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It wouldn't surprise me if no-one made such a mount.  They wouldn't want to be liable for the damage it could cause to your head in an impact, either directly or by weakening the helmet.  It would also be more work to fit and far less universal, limiting sales.

The least bad way of doing this would be to drill the helmet, and screw outwards into the mount, choosing screws with the flattest heads possible.  Then at least you wouldn't have spikes on the inside.  But drilling the helmet would only be strong enough for the camera  with a hard shell, like a whitewater helmet or a minority of bike helmets.  You'd end up cutting away at the foam for the screws to have somewhere to go.  So by this point you'd have weakened the shell and the energy-absorbing foam - not a good start.

A design using clamp screws through existing vents would be no good either - unless designed for a very limited range of helmets it wouldn't fit, and would likely put hard bits where you don't want them.

I have a helmet camera for kayaking (cylindrical and side mounted rather than on top like a GoPro).  That's held on with a strap, stabilised by thin thread.  If I hit my head it will come off without much force, rather than yanking my head round.  But there's also a light lanyard attaching it to the helmet strap using a plastic link that I can spring open with 2 fingers (it's carabiner-style keyring , so I wouldn't lose it, unless it snagged and I floated away - better that than it holding me in a strainer. I've used similar breakaway approaches for head-mounted lights on the bike - the thinnest cable ties, which snap if I don't duck enough for a low doorway.

Even the glued mounts carry some risk - they're actually really strong, and a knock in the wrong direction can drive the edge of the mount through a helmet shell.

Comment: There are a few mounts that strap through helmet vents.  Not knowing what the helmet in question is, or even the activity type, I can't honestly suggest you use them, but they may be worth a look.

Comment: I don't think there is a least bad way to screw something into a helmet. Just don't do it.

Comment: @njzk2 I agree don't do it, but woodscrews pointing inwards and penetrating most of the way through the foam would be far worse than something thin and flat on the inside